# customise images for google plus in ShareThis plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, sharethis

I am using wordpress ShareThis plugin, I want to use customise image for google plus,Any body can help??

I had already used: st_plusone_custom (made and custom class) and ' st_url=''> but it is not working.

Reply soon is really helpful

Regards,
Firoja

Comment: I had the same issue but not in wordpress.. any work around?